# Kafka Connect topic.key.ignore not works as expected

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

As I understand from the documentation of kafka connect this configuration should ignore the keys for metricbeat and filebeat topic but not for alarms. But kafka connect does not ignore any key.

So that's the fully json config that i pushing to kafka-connect over rest

```
{
 "auto.create.indices.at.start": false,
 "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector",
 "connection.url": "http://elasticsearch:9200",
 "connection.timeout.ms": 5000,
 "read.timeout.ms": 5000,
 "tasks.max": "5",
 "topics": "filebeat,metricbeat,alarms",
 "behavior.on.null.values": "delete",
 "behavior.on.malformed.documents": "warn",
 "flush.timeout.ms":60000,
 "max.retries":42,
 "retry.backoff.ms": 100,
 "max.in.flight.requests": 5,
 "max.buffered.records":20000,
 "batch.size":4096,
 "drop.invalid.message": true,
 "schema.ignore": true,
 "topic.key.ignore": "metricbeat,filebeat",
 "key.ignore": false
 "name": "elasticsearch-ecs-connector",
 "type.name": "_doc",
 "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
 "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
 "transforms":"routeTS",
 "transforms.routeTS.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampRouter",
 "transforms.routeTS.topic.format":"${topic}-${timestamp}",
 "transforms.routeTS.timestamp.format":"YYYY.MM.dd",
 "errors.tolerance": "all" ,
 "errors.log.enable": false ,
 "errors.log.include.messages": false,
 "errors.deadletterqueue.topic.name":"logstream-dlq",
 "errors.deadletterqueue.context.headers.enable":true ,
 "errors.deadletterqueue.topic.replication.factor": 1
}
```

That's the logging during start of the connector

```
[2020-05-01 21:07:49,960] INFO ElasticsearchSinkConnectorConfig values:
    auto.create.indices.at.start = false
    batch.size = 4096
    behavior.on.malformed.documents = warn
    behavior.on.null.values = delete
    compact.map.entries = true
    connection.compression = false
    connection.password = null
    connection.timeout.ms = 5000
    connection.url = [http://elasticsearch:9200]
    connection.username = null
    drop.invalid.message = true
    elastic.https.ssl.cipher.suites = null
    elastic.https.ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    elastic.https.ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    elastic.https.ssl.key.password = null
    elastic.https.ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    elastic.https.ssl.keystore.location = null
    elastic.https.ssl.keystore.password = null
    elastic.https.ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    elastic.https.ssl.protocol = TLS
    elastic.https.ssl.provider = null
    elastic.https.ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    elastic.https.ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    elastic.https.ssl.truststore.location = null
    elastic.https.ssl.truststore.password = null
    elastic.https.ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    elastic.security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    flush.timeout.ms = 60000
    key.ignore = false
    linger.ms = 1
    max.buffered.records = 20000
    max.in.flight.requests = 5
    max.retries = 42
    read.timeout.ms = 5000
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    schema.ignore = true
    topic.index.map = []
    topic.key.ignore = [metricbeat, filebeat]
    topic.schema.ignore = []
    type.name = _doc
    write.method = insert
```

Iam using Confluent Platform 5.5.0

Comment: So in Elasticsearch are you seeing the Kafka message key as the document `_id` for all three indices?

Comment: Yes I do. metricbeat-2020.05.01+2+1391 for example. But not the key as id that I set.

Comment: Can you confirm that the config in the question now matches what you're running? Because the update you posted had `key.ignore=true` (whereas before it was `key.ignore=false`)

Comment: Sorry. That's a copy paste error from wrong branch. key.ignore=false is the config that not works. As I understand from docu is that topic.key.ignore=<topics> should set key.ignore to true for the particular topics. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Let's recap here, because there have been several edits to your question and problem statement :)

1. You want to stream multiple topics to Elasticsearch with a single connector
2. You want to use the message key for some topics as the Elasticsearch document ID, and for others you don't and want to use the Kafka message coordinates instead (topic+partition+offset)
3. You are trying to do this with `key.ignore` and `topic.key.ignore` settings

Here's my test data in three topics, `test01`, `test02`, `test03`:

```
ksql> PRINT test01 from beginning;
Key format: KAFKA_STRING
Value format: AVRO or KAFKA_STRING
rowtime: 2020/05/12 11:08:32.441 Z, key: X, value: {"COL1": 1, "COL2": "FOO"}
rowtime: 2020/05/12 11:08:32.594 Z, key: Y, value: {"COL1": 2, "COL2": "BAR"}

ksql> PRINT test02 from beginning;
Key format: KAFKA_STRING
Value format: AVRO or KAFKA_STRING
rowtime: 2020/05/12 11:08:50.865 Z, key: X, value: {"COL1": 1, "COL2": "FOO"}
rowtime: 2020/05/12 11:08:50.936 Z, key: Y, value: {"COL1": 2, "COL2": "BAR"}

ksql> PRINT test03 from beginning;
Key format: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ - no data processed
Value format: AVRO or KAFKA_STRING
rowtime: 2020/05/12 11:16:15.166 Z, key: <null>, value: {"COL1": 1, "COL2": "FOO"}
rowtime: 2020/05/12 11:16:46.404 Z, key: <null>, value: {"COL1": 2, "COL2": "BAR"}
```

With this data I create a connector (I'm using ksqlDB but it's the same as if you use the REST API directly):

```sql
CREATE SINK CONNECTOR SINK_ELASTIC_TEST WITH (
  'connector.class' = 'io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector',
  'connection.url'  = 'http://elasticsearch:9200',
  'key.converter'   = 'org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter',
  'type.name'       = '_doc',
  'topics'          = 'test02,test01,test03',
  'key.ignore'      = 'false',
  'topic.key.ignore'= 'test02,test03',
  'schema.ignore'   = 'false'
);
```

The resulting indices are created and populated in Elasticsearch. Here's the index and document ID of the documents:

```sh
➜ curl -s http://localhost:9200/test01/_search \
    -H 'content-type: application/json' \
    -d '{ "size": 5 }' |jq -c '.hits.hits[] | [._index, ._id]'
["test01","Y"]
["test01","X"]

➜ curl -s http://localhost:9200/test02/_search \
    -H 'content-type: application/json' \
    -d '{ "size": 5 }' |jq -c '.hits.hits[] | [._index, ._id]'
["test02","test02+0+0"]
["test02","test02+0+1"]

➜ curl -s http://localhost:9200/test03/_search \
    -H 'content-type: application/json' \
    -d '{ "size": 5 }' |jq -c '.hits.hits[] | [._index, ._id]'
["test03","test03+0+0"]
["test03","test03+0+1"]
```

So `key.ignore` is the default and for `test01` in effect, which means that the key of the messages are used for the document ID.

Topics `test02` and `test03` are listed for `topic.key.ignore` which means that the key of the message *is* ignored (i.e. in effect `key.ignore=true`), and thus the document ID is the topic/partition/offset of the message.

I would recommend, given that I've proven out above that this *does* work, that you start your test again from scratch to double-check your working.

Comment: Sorry. Sure for metricbeat and filebeat topic the behaviuour is ok. But why for alarms ? Instead of the window key '1588456240000/1588456260000' the _id is 'alarms-2020.05.02+0+23'.

Comment: What you're seeing there (`alarms-2020.05.02+0+23`) doesn't match the config you've shared, because there's a timestamp being inserted. So either the topic isn't actually what you've got in your config, or you're using a different config from the one in your question. Can you clarify?

Comment: The shown config is the log output of kakfa-connect. The indices are configured with timestamprouter. This setting is not printed but works

Comment: I got the error [2020-05-12 13:44:55,153] ERROR Can't convert record from topic/partition/offset metricbeat-2020.05.12/0/8984705. Error message: Key is used as document id and can not be null. (io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchWriter. So that's right that metricbeat is keyless. But the topic.key.ignore=metricbeat should ignore it .Am I wrong?

Comment: Robin Moffatt Thanks for the explanation but still inclution of topic name in topic.key.ignore is not helping.                                                                                           schema.ignore = true
 topic.index.map = []   This part i have copied from logs and still getting the error key cannot be null for the topic metricbeat. So won't use the defalut topic+partition+offset as document id?
 topic.key.ignore = ["metricbeat"]